# Opening Crystal Report in a new page in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Is there anyway I can open the PDF in a new page instead of the same page in ASP.net.

I am calling this code on click of a button. I want this to be opened in a new page.

Below is the code

```
ReportDocument fpReport = new ReportDocument();
            fpReport.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rpt");

            fpReport.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "MyReport");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an onclick attribute to the button which calls some JS to open a new window, there is no way to do this as you described.